# GraphQL - Querying a list of objects with varying attribute names?

Tags: database, list, nosql, graphql, graphql-js

I have a set of data that looks like this. I cannot determine how to list out the contents under `entries` in the example below, (if it's possible.)

Below is an example of the data structure. Each object follows the same layout as the first entry. Thanks for any pointers you can give me!

```js
entries: {
    2018-01-14T14:30:00-05:00: {
        name: "Jerry",
        guess: 75
    },
    2018-01-14T15:15:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-14T19:15:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-14T23:00:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-15T00:00:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-15T03:15:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-15T06:30:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-15T07:15:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-15T11:30:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-15T15:45:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-15T19:15:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-15T18:45:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-16T14:45:00-05:00: {},
    2018-01-16T18:45:00-05:00: {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your type for an entry is defined along these lines:

```
type Entry {
  name: String
  guess: Int
  timestamp: String
}
```

You can just iterate through the keys of the `entries` object like this:

```
return Object.keys(entries).map(key => {
  return Object.assign({ timestamp: key }, entries[key])
})
```

If your intent is to return the `entries` object **as is** through GraphQL, that's trickier since each timestamp would have to be defined as as a field inside a type. Even if you did so dynamically, any changes to the underlying data could cause you to end up with an invalid schema. The easiest way around that is to utilize a custom JSON scalar, [as described here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars.html).